# @inproceedings{papername,proceedingsname, possible?

Tags: bibtex

I remember seeing somewhere this syntax for referencing proceedings:

```
@proceedings{proc01,
...
}
```

and then

```
@inproceedings{paper01,proc01,
...
}
```

So that all fields from proc01 automatically get copied into the fitting fields of paper01 (i.e. title becomes booktitle, years becomes year,...).
However all bibtex manuals I consult don't show this syntax and bibtex gives me the following error, does this exist or not? Do I need some external software for it?

```
"," immediately follows a field name---line 590 of file paper.bib
 : @inproceedings{paper01,proc01
```

Comment: No, you can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen such a possibility in BibTeX (or `biblatex`). There is a kind of inheritance with the `crossref` field:

```
@incollection{companion-bib,
  crossref      = "companion",
  title         = "Bibliography Generation",
  chapter       = 13,
  pages         = "371-420",
}
```

is the example in the “Tame the BeaST” manual about BibTeX ([`texdoc tamethebeast`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) where, of course, you have an entry such as

```
@book{companion,
  author        = "Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Franck and Samarin, Alexander",
  title         = "The {{\LaTeX}} {C}ompanion",
  publisher     = "Addison-Wesley",
  year          = 1993,
}
```

The `crossref` field can be used also with `@inproceedings` and reference to any entry.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267910/) note that BibTeX requires that cross-referenced entries occur ***after*** all entries which reference them in the `.bib` file. So, aside from the syntax issues etc. in the example given in the question, it would not work to have the `@proceedings` entry *before* the `@inproceedings` one which references it.

There are some additional restrictions. For example, you cannot have chains of cross-references. If `<entry 1>` includes `crossref = {<entry 2>}`, then `<entry 2>` should not include a `crossref` field: the information in this entry should be enough standalone.

If you use Biblatex, especially with Biber, some of these restrictions are lifted and some additional options are available. In addition to `crossref`, there is `xdata`, for example. `xdata` is like `crossref` but an `@xdata` entry is never added to the bibliography as an independent entry: it serves only as a source of data for use by other entries.

You can also define 'entry sets':

```
@set{set-things,
        entryset                        =       {<key1>,<key2>,<key3>},
        title                           =       {Set of Connected Entries}}
```

If `<set-things>` is cited, all entries in the set will be added to the bibliography and grouped together. The Biblatex manual has all the gory details.